# Python nested for loop only running once, then skips the rest of the iterations

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want this code to get 15 times the amount of data it got. When it runs, the first time it goes into all of the for loops, and then prints out the answer, but when it goes to loop the second time in the "for num in range(0,15):" loop, it goes into the "for df in page:" and then doesn't go any deeper into the other loops and just returns the "page_counter" incrementing by 200 as it should.

What should I do to make it run the final nested for loop every time the "for num in range(0,15):" loops?

```
 import pandas as pd

 symbol = 0
 for num in range(symbol,1):
     page_counter =0
     right = 1
     down = 0
     for num in range(0,15):
         page = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=a&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2005&enddate=Mar+2%2C+2017&num=200&ei=Aom4WPizNcWO2AaSnZ3YBg'+ str(page_counter), attrs = {'class': 'gf-table'}, header=0)

         for df in page:
             for num in range(down,200):
                 open_data = df.at[down, 'Open']
                 high_data = df.at[down, 'High']
                 low_data = df.at[down, 'Low']
                 close_data = df.at[down, 'Close']
                 #volume_data = df.at[down, 'Volume']

                 print(open_data)

                 down += 1
         page_counter += 200
         print(page_counter)
      symbol += 1
```

P.S. I know my code is a bit janky right now, this is just a quick idea I had.

Comment: You are using the same `num` variable in both inner and outer for loops, You might want to use a different variable name for each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare down = 0 inside `for num in range(0,15):`

after 1st run down = 200 so this loop not satisfying  `for num in range(down,200):` range condition.

```
 import pandas as pd

 symbol = 0
 for num in range(symbol,1):
     page_counter =0
     right = 1
     for num in range(0,15):
         down = 0
         page = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=a&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2005&enddate=Mar+2%2C+2017&num=200&ei=Aom4WPizNcWO2AaSnZ3YBg'+ str(page_counter), attrs = {'class': 'gf-table'}, header=0)

         for df in page:
             for num in range(down,200):
                 open_data = df.at[down, 'Open']
                 high_data = df.at[down, 'High']
                 low_data = df.at[down, 'Low']
                 close_data = df.at[down, 'Close']
                 #volume_data = df.at[down, 'Volume']

                 print(open_data)

                 down += 1
         page_counter += 200
         print(page_counter)
      symbol += 1
```

Comment: I would, but for my actual code the down = 0 has to be up there, because it is writing to a specific cell in an excel sheet. So, the cell would just overwrite. Thanks though

Comment: @AlexBorland  `for num in range(down,200):` this will executed only once in your code or you can use another variable.

Comment: The first time I tried that it didn't work, because I didn't change all of them. It worked though after that. Thanks